# Создание кэша на java

Tags: java, кэширование

Задали задание. Создать универсальную реализацию кэша.

Что такое этот КЭШ cache?
Для чего он нужен?
Где применяется (самые простые варианты)?
Какую литературу по этому можно прочитать?

Полная версия задания такая:

> Создать универсальную реализацию кэша(ы) с помощью приведенных ниже алгоритмов. Все кэши должны поддерживать нить безопасном режиме, быть универсальными и не использовать никаких сторонних разработчиков, помимо JSE.
>
> Least Recently Used (LRU) cache
>   Least Frequently Used (LFU) cache

Comment: Не каждый, кто знает что такое кэш, сможет создать универсальную реализацию. Где такие задания дают?

Comment: [Кэширование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88) — довольно обширная тема и дать простой ответ на Ваш вопрос нельзя. Попробуйте поискать материалы в поисковике (их много) и задать более точный вопрос. [Из справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): `Вопросы должны быть узкими — если для ответа на вопрос требуется написать книгу, он явно не для этого ресурса.`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ))). Надеюсь мое задание не состоит из объема в книгу. Очень на это надеюсь))). Полная версия задания такая:                  Создать универсальную реализацию кэша(ы) с помощью приведенных ниже алгоритмов. Все кэши должны поддерживать нить безопасном режиме, быть универсальными и не использовать никаких сторонних разработчиков, помимо JSE.                                                                           Least Recently Used (LRU) cache
Least Frequently Used (LFU) cache